# border-radius shows slight color from parent div background in corners

Tags: css

I have an issue where you can clearly see the parent in the top right and top left corners of the child.

I have tried with using `overflow: hidden;` on parent as well as using `border-radius` on the child.

The issue is a bit hard to explain but you can clearly see the issue on the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lccaf0u/

edit: Here is an image showing the issue as well (using chrome)

[image: The issue]

Comment: I couldn't figure it out... but here are some additional tests. making the radius bigger really shows the issue clearly: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lccaf0u/1/  Good luck!

Comment: I'm clear on the problem, but not on what the layout is supposed to be when it comes to 'inner' / 'outer' - does the inner need a border radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix would be to make the `outer` element have a large radius than the `inner` for only the top portion

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

.outer, .outer2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 5px 5px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.inner, .inner2 {
  background: #111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Edit: It's happening because that is how the browser renders it. Not all browsers will produce the same result.

Comment: This is a way around it, but not an answer to why it's happening.

Comment: It's happening because that is how the browser renders it.  Not all browsers will produce the same result.

Comment: That sounds like more of an answer. Maybe you should include it.

Comment: I included it but in all fairness the question doesn't specifically ask as to why it is happening.  One can assume they are just looking for a fix.